# HVAC plastic drainage tube snapped off outside

Tags: hvac

The plastic tube where the condensate drains outside has broken off partly. I would say about 2/3 of it broke off. It still points away from the house a little so shouldn’t get on the wall. Should I fix this or is it fine to have a shorter length?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to tell without a picture; would you add one to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Is this a backup drain or is it the primary drain? Usually this type is a backup and only has water dripping from it when the primary drain is plugged and water is overflowing into an external pan under the unit.